# Currency not changing in magento cms page

Tags: magento-1.9, cms-block, multicurrency

I am using a custom theme for my Magento Store. On home page, I am using 2 carousal( For Products ) one from CMS block and one from Static block. I have 2 currencies one is INR and second one is USD. If i am changing currency then its reflect in static blcok carousal but its not reflecting in CMS block carousal. Can anyone guide me how can i solve it?

Comment: How are those blocks defined ? Add that code with the question.

Comment: Hi, If i am using cms block carousal in static block then currency is changing.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because the pages are set to a certain pageview? The static blocks are not set to a static view.

That could be one reason....

Comment: I am new in magento so can you guide me, How to check it.

Comment: Can you please explain more